# FIPS validated algorithm to store passwords in a database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, fips

I am looking for a FIPS validated hash algorithm to store passwords in the database.
I did use the following code but I still get the error

> This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms.

```
SHA1CryptoServiceProvider Testsha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hashedBytes;
UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
hashed = Testsha1.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(strPassword));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < hashed.Length; i++)
{
    sbuilder.Append(hashed[i].ToString("x2"));
}
string Password = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see that error message?

Comment: @n8wrl that exception is thrown by some Security Classes, like SHA1Managed, when the EnableFIPS security policy is enforced.

Comment: I did see the error when i try to run my web application.

Comment: @Macnique - That code posted should not cause that exception - `SHA1CryptoServiceProvider` will use Window's CSP. Please verify that in the stack trace, and post it in your question as well.

Comment: @vcsjones I am using the SHA1 as i read that its FIPS compliant.Does it have something to do with the IIS ?

Comment: it looks like adding the following in web.config under system.web section <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/> solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following line in web.config under system.web section

`<machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" ecryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/>`

solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

Plain SHA-1 should not be used to store passwords. PBKDF2 is a good choice. In .net you can use it with the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class. See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2131/reference-implementation-of-c-password-hashing-and-verification/2136#2136

You might need to change the underlying hash function to SHA-256. From what I remember SHA-1 isn't NIST approved.

Comment: SHA1 is acceptable by NIST (part of FIPS Pub 180) - it would be nice if Microsoft gave control of the HMAC algorithm used for it to use SHA256. Microsoft's implementation of it in the CSP is [140-2 approved](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cmvp/documents/140-1/1401val2004.htm#405).

Comment: it looks like adding the following in web.config under system.web section <machineKey validationKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="AutoGenerate,IsolateApps" validation="3DES" decryption="3DES"/> solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

> I am looking for a FIPS validated hash algorithm to store passwords in the database.

Use one of the hashes from the SHA-2 family. For example, SHA256.

Do not use a managed class - they are not FIPS validated. Instead, use `SHA256CryptoServiceProvider` and friends.